# Manipulating a volume cube via it's mesh -- Volume remains unaffected

Tags: shaders, volumetrics, ocean-simulation

Attempting to manipulate a volume cube by manipulating the mesh.

I've subdived / pinned the top face of the mesh to an ocean sim with a shrinkwrap *(trying to simulate an underwater volume so I can pan my camera below the surface seamlessly.)*

The mesh is definitely being manipulated but the volume remains unaffected and maintains the shape of the original mesh during the simulation.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why that's not working for you; I probably couldn't say without a file.  However, what I would do in that situation is a little different, and testing it out, it works just fine:

[image]

Rather than creating a separate volumetric mesh, which is never going to completely agree with the ocean surface, I simply solidified my ocean.  In order to flatten the bottom and take it to the depth I need, I mark the solidify shell with a vertex group and then shrinkwrap it to a non-rendering plane.

Worth mentioning that this is Cycles only, and this isn't going to work in Eevee without multiple renders and a decent bit of shader wizardry.